# Сохранение стрима WebRTC

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

Имеется стандартная реализация веб-конференции WebRTC p2p. Используется socket.io и node-static как сервер. Мне необходимо писать оба стрима (оба видео) "налету" в видеофайл. Формат не имеет значения.

Запись блоба с последующим скачиванием или закачиванием на сервер это просто, но вот как писать стрим "сразу"? Пользователь не должен нажимать кнопок "запись" или "сохранить запись". Он может просто закрыть вкладку конференции и уйти. При этом файл на сервере уже должен быть. То есть его как-то нужно туда писать, например через вебсокеты.

Это вообще реально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри сервер Kurrento... Сам пока успел его поюзать как раз для такого функционала, как у тебя.
Т.е. клиент(браузер) коннектится к курренто-серверу как к пиру и все - сервер может либо писать в файл, либо транскодить, либо бродкастить далее этот поток.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: Alexey, да, я тоже к нему пришёл. Если не хочется нагружать клиента, то нужен gateway сервер. У меня получилось писать и с клиента, но грузит CPU. Если машинка слабая, то видео лагает.

Comment: Ну да, не каждый клиент потянет. А как сервер - сколько одновременно подключенных клиентов держит?